# How do I return the indexing of the matching values of the Application.Match function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code. The "Application.Match" function searches in two sheets for the same value and returns true if there is a match.

How can I have the indices of these two values so I can use them (row and column)?

```
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1)) Then
         For iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Worksheets.Count
            bln = False
            var = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, 
Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(var) Then
                bln = True
                  Else
               Exit For
            End If
         Next iSheet
```

Comment: Right now you are returning `True` if the match is not found, as you are in the Else part of the if.

Comment: yeah sorry, I am gonna edit it. But the meaning is the same of my question!

Comment: Sorry, `var` is the row, and you set the column to `1`.

Comment: So how can I have the index of both cells? meaning that how can i use both cells for another comparison inside the "if" ? thanks for the follow up!

Comment: Is not Scott's comment saying you have (var,1) ? Can you give an example of what you were hoping to do inside the If for another comparison?